# How to do sorting after groupby and aggregation on a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having a Pandas Dataframe and I'm doing a groupby on two columns and have a couple of aggregate functions on a column. Here is how my code looks like

```
df2 = df[X,Y, Z].groupby([X,Y]).agg([np.mean, np.max, np.min]).reset_index()
```

It find the aggregate functions on the column Z.

I need to sort by let's say `min` (i.e. `sort_values('min')`) column but it keeps complaining that 'min' column does not exist. How can I do that

Comment: The problem i’m having is the column ‘min’ is not picked by python

Comment: What is the output dataframe of your statement df2.head()?

Comment: Please see my edit, the aggregate fun is on column Z

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are generating a pd.MultiIndex, you must use a tuple in sort_values.

Try:

```
df2.sort_values(('Z','amin'))
```